# Taylor series in two variables?

Tags: taylor-expansion

how can I calculate the taylor series for a two-dimensional function?

Example:
\begin{equation*}
f(x,y) = Log(1+x+y).
\end{equation*}
I have

- $f_x = (1+x+y)^{-1} = f_y$.
- $f_{xx} = -(1+x+y)^{-2} = f_{yy} = f_{xy} = f_{xy}$
- $f_{xxx} = 2(1+x+y)^{-3} = f_{yyy} = ...$
- $f_{xxxx} = -6(1+x+y)^{-4} = ...$

and so on

Now my taylor series at point $(a_1, a_2) = (0,0)$ is:
\begin{equation*}
Tf(x,y) = Log[1] + f_x (0,0)(x) + f_y(0,0)(y) + \frac{1}{2!} \cdot [f_{xx}(0,0)(x)^2+f_{yy}(0,0)(y)^2+2f_{xy}(0,0)xy] + ... 
= 0 + x + y + \frac{1}{2!} [-x^2 - y^2 -2xy] + \frac{1}{3!} [2x^3+2y^3+4x^2y+4xy^2] + ...
\end{equation*}

Is this correct and is there a way to write it down a bit more compact?

Comment: The compact representation of Taylor series in higher dimensions requires tensors of high order. Tensors of order 0 are scalars; order 1 are vectors; order 2 are matrices. In general tensors of order $k+1$ act on tensors of order $k$ to give back tensors of order $k$. Additionally tensors of order $k+1$ can take in $k+1$ tensors of order $k$ to give back a scalar. For $k=0$ this is through the dot product; for $k=1$ it is through the bilinear form $(x,y) \to x^T A y$ for a matrix $A$.

Comment: In the Taylor series context, the first order term is the inner product with a gradient; the second order term is a bilinear form with the Hessian matrix (a matrix containing all the second partial derivatives); the third order term is a trilinear form with a third order tensor containing third partial derivatives; etc.

Comment: In short, you probably don't want to do it this way (I know when I studied this the first time, I only got more confused). I would encourage doing it the way the other answers have suggested, by treating $x+y$ as one variable and then doing algebra.

Comment: That is a very useful commentary - thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry, I made one error: a tensor of order $k$ can take in $k$ *vectors* to give back a scalar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slightly nicer way: Write $f(x,y)=\log(1+x+y)$ as $g(u)=\log(1+u)$ where $u=x+y$.
Expand about $u=0$:
$$\log(1+u)=u-\frac{u^{2}}{2}+\frac{u^{3}}{3}\ldots$$
Then substituting for $u$:
$$\log(1+x+y)=(x+y)-\frac{(x+y)^{2}}{2}+\frac{(x+y)^{3}}{3}\ldots$$
Which is exactly what you wrote down.

Comment: Thank you! Dont' we have to proof that this substitution is allowed (due to the partial derivatives)?

Comment: No, it's fine. Notice that $\frac{dg}{du}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$

Answer (score 0):

You are correct there, and your notation has already make the expression looks much more nicer in my opinion.